# The problem with alpha channel MovieClip (Actionscript3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip, alpha

Here is my code:

```
var menu = new Menu ();
menu.x = 0;
menu.y = 0;
addChild (menu);
menu.alpha = 0;
TweenLite.to (menu, 10, (alpha: 1));
```

This works, but transparency varies for each element MovieClip separately, but I would like that would have changed the whole MovieClip transparency as a single image.

Menu(); is generated from XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option: create a Sprite or MovieClip object, and add all your menu objects as its children (and not as children of the parent class). Then, call TweenLite on your grouped object. (Note: I haven't used TweenLite specifically, but I have used this technique with other tweening libraries)

Answer (score 0):

I helped the following:

```
menu.blendMode = "layer"
```